# Illegal reflective access by com.intellij.util.ReflectionUtil to method java.util.ResourceBundle.setParent(java.util.ResourceBundle)

Tags: java, kotlin, warnings, java-15

I've made some kotlin code in VSCode

one of them is:

```
fun main() {
println("Hello world")
}
```

And when i run it, i get:

```
[Running] cd "d:\Coding\Dicoding\" && kotlinc a.kt -include-runtime -d a.jar && java -jar a.jar
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: Options -Xverify:none and -noverify were deprecated in JDK 13 and will likely be removed in a future release.
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by com.intellij.util.ReflectionUtil to method java.util.ResourceBundle.setParent(java.util.ResourceBundle)
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of com.intellij.util.ReflectionUtil
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
Hello world

[Done] exited with code=0 in 2.976 seconds
```

It works, but i can't hide or fix the warnings, i use JDK 15

i didn't get those warnings on IntelliJ

Comment: The first thing to try, is to run those commands separately instead of joining them with `&&`, to see, which command produced which warnings.

Comment: I am also facing this error :(